# What does Array(array.length).fill(0) mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning and practicing hooks useState in react js. For example, when declaring a state variable like this,

```
const [votes, setVotes] = useState(0)
```

I know that the 0 value in useState() means that votes is initialized with starting value of 0. However, advancing a little bit, like this,

```
const [votes, setVotes] = useState(() => Array(fruits.length).fill(0))
```

Given an array,

```
const fruits = ["kiwi", "banana", "mango", "apple", "durian"]
```

I am a little confused with the Array in the second state variable wrapping fruits.length, why do we have to wrap it with Array ? fruits is already an array. And just to make sure that I understand, the .fill(0) means that we will initialize every element in the array fruit with 0? Am I right ? To give a context, I have an array fruits and two buttons, one is to vote, and the other is to select randomly the next fruit. Every time I vote, the vote will increase and when I click the other button, random fruits will be displayed and the vote will be 0 for fruits that haven't got voted. This is the vote button code,

```
const handleVotes = () => { 
    setVotes((votes) => 
      votes.map((vote, index) => index === selected ? vote + 1 : vote)
    )
 }
```

Comment: if you do `fruits.fill(0)` it will overwrite all values in `fruits` with `0` for each value. `Array(fruits.length).fill(0)` makes a **new** array filled with `0`s, matching the length of `fruits`. run it in a console to see for yourself. also note `() => ...` precedes the state, this is a lazy state initializer and runs **only once** when the component is initialized. this is important otherwise `Array(fruits.length).fill(0)` would be evaluated during each render, even though the value would be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping over the entire array of fruits is rather inefficient. We can use a `Map` which allows us to create a *mapping* between fruits and their votes. This allows us to update a fruit directly, without having to evaluate a condition against each element. Run the demo below and vote for your favourite!

```js
function App({ fruits }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(fruits[0])
  const [votes, setVotes] = React.useState(() => new Map)
  const select = fruit => event => {
    setSelected(fruit)
  }
  const vote = event => {
    setVotes(vs =>
      new Map(vs).set(selected, (vs.get(selected) || 0) + 1)
    )
  }
  return <div>
    {fruits.map(f =>
      <button
        onClick={select(f)}
        className={selected == f ? "selected" : ""}
        children={f}
      />
    )}
    <button onClick={vote} children="vote" />
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries([...votes]))}</pre>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App fruits={["","",""]} />, document.body)
```

```css
.selected { border-color: teal; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array(array.length).fill(0)` is a JavaScript expression that creates a new array filled with a specified value. The expression creates an array with the length equal to the length of the `array` variable passed as an argument. The .`fill(0)` method is then used to fill the entire array with the value 0.

Here's an example:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const newArray = Array(array.length).fill(0);
console.log(newArray);
// Output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In this example, `array` is an array with 5 elements, so `Array(array.length).fill(0)` creates a new array with 5 elements, all filled with the value `0`.

I hope this helps!